# Does #1 have any former training?

Tags: 6-underground

In the movie 6 underground, we find that the team is composed of different people from various backgrounds. Among those is #1 a.k.a. the Billionaire, who after faking his own death decided to form the ghost group. Presumably #1 doesn't have any formal training in fighting as was shown many times in the movie in various different scenes. However, there is one scene where he manages to kill 4 enemies very quickly, prompting #7 to ask him where he learnt to fight like that. To which #1 responds: "It doesn't matter."

**My question:**

Does #1 really know how to fight or is this just another Ryan Reynolds action quirk?

Comment: How did you come to this evaluation??  "Presumably #1 doesn't have any formal training in fighting as was shown many times in the movie in various different scenes"

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter.

More precisely: it is not answered in the movie.

However, he does fit the *Bored Billionaire Playboy Turned Vigilante* trope à la Batman, Green Arrow, or Iron Man. It is quite conceivable that before turning vigilante, he dabbled in extreme sports, world record breaking, adventurism, or space tourism (see Mark Shuttleworth, Charles Simyoni, Richard Branson, or Steve Fossett for real-life examples).

It is plausible that he took part in activities such as hunting or shooting, and that he attended martial arts training. In the opening scene of the movie he is shown to be a prolific aerobatic pilot (and possibly skydiver) which at least requires well above-average physical fitness, stamina, reflexes, hand-eye coordination, and spatial orientation.

You can learn *a lot* if you have nothing else to do and time and money are no object.

Again, as a real-world example, let's look at Steve Fossett: he flew sailplanes, zeppelins, motor airplanes, jet airplanes, and balloons. And he set multiple world records in each of those. He also set multiple world records as a solo sailor. And one day, he decided to swim across the English channel, despite the fact that he couldn't swim. He learned to swim just for this event, and it wasn't even for any record – he just wanted to swim across the English channel.

So, given that he had unlimited time and money, which allowed him to buy the best training possible and commit to it full-time, it is plausible that he simply learned this "just for fun" during his playboy days.

In addition to that, if I remember correctly, a significant amount of time passes between the gas attack on the refugee camp which prompts his metamorphosis from playboy to vigilante and the first mission, giving him plenty of time to train *specifically* for his new "non-life".

Comment: We also see a couple shots around their base showing targets riddled with holes.  #1 could have spent a lot of time practicing in his own little range there.